# Convert week date to calendar date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have column with dates in format

> year/number_of_week_in_year/number_of_day_of_the_week, for example:
>
> 2015015 =  01.01.2015

How to write query which convert this date to `RRRRmmdd` format?

Comment: Why is fifth day in year `01.01.2015`? 5th day is either `05.01.02015` or `02.01.2015`(if the calendar-week started at 29.12.2014 which seemed to be the case)

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I *believe* this is based on the concept that weekday 5 is a Thursday *(Sunday being Weekday 1)*, and so 2015's first "week" only has 3 days in it.  ***(OP, please clarify.)***

Comment: @MatBailie Yes, Sunday its first day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an untested answer for you, as I don't have access to SQL Server to fiddle around (on my phone at the moment).

The easy part is to get at DATE value for the year...

```
DATEADD(year, (input / 1000) - 1900), 0)
```

Then you need to add a certain number of days to it...
- 7 days for each week (not including week 1)
- 1 day of each day of the week

```
((input / 10) % 100 - 1) * 7
+ input % 10
```

Then deducting a number of days depending on the day of the week that year started on.

```
DATEPART(weekday, <your year as a date>)
```

Which seems to give...

```
DATEADD(
    day,
    ((input / 10) % 100 - 1) * 7
    + input % 10
    - DATEPART(weekday, DATEADD(year, (input / 1000) - 1900, 0)),
    DATEADD(year, (input / 1000) - 1900, 0)
)
```

Using your example...

```
DATEADD(
    day,
    ((2015015 / 10) % 100 - 1) * 7
    + 2015015 % 10
    - DATEPART(weekday, DATEADD(year, (2015015 / 1000) - 1900, 0)),
    DATEADD(year, (2015015 / 1000) - 1900), 0)
)
```

=>

```
DATEADD(
    day,
    (01 - 1) * 7
    + 5
    - DATEPART(weekday, DATEADD(year, 2015 - 1900, 0)),
    DATEADD(year, 2015 - 1900, 0)
)
```

=>

```
DATEADD(
    day,
    0 * 7
    + 5
    - DATEPART(weekday, '2015-01-01'),
    '2015-01-01'
)
```

=>

```
DATEADD(
    day,
    0 * 7
    + 5
    - 5,
   '2015-01-01'
)
```

=>

```
'2015-01-01'
```

Comment: Great answer, especially on a phone! I'm curious about the first line `DATEADD(year, (input / 1000) - 1900), 0)`. I presume this is based on `input` being an `int` right? I assumed (for no valid reason) it was a string, so I'm just making sure you're not using some cool new string hack I'm not aware of! :-)

Comment: @MichaelMcMullin - Yeah, I should have stated that assumption, I just went by the example being `2015015 = 01.01.2015`, which is easily stored as an INT.

Comment: @MatBailie What should I change in query to set new start day of the week, for example Monday?

Comment: @Kulis - When it comes to using `DATEPART` the first day of the week depends on the server's settings.  From recollection you can override the server's settings for a ***session*** by using `SET DATEFIRST = ?` *(`1` for Monday, `7` for Sunday)*.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution I threw together, probably not the cleverest way to do it but hopefully makes sense:

```
DECLARE @inDate CHAR(7),
        @inYear CHAR(4),
        @inWeek INT,
        @inDay  INT,
        @OutDate DATETIME;

SET @inDate = '2015015';
SET @inYear = SUBSTRING(@inDate, 0, 5);
SET @inWeek = CAST(SUBSTRING(@inDate, 5, 2) AS INT) - 1 -- Reduce by 1 because it will be added to start of year
SET @inDay  = CAST(SUBSTRING(@inDate, 7, 1) AS INT)

SET @OutDate = CAST(@inYear + '-01-01' AS DATETIME)
SET @OutDate = DATEADD(dd, -DATEPART(weekday, @OutDate) + @inDay, @OutDate)
SET @OutDate = DATEADD(ww, @inWeek, @OutDate)

PRINT @OutDate -- Gives Jan 1 2015
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create simple function to do this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetDate ( @Date AS NVARCHAR(7) )
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @WeekDayOfYearStart INT ,
        @WeekNum INT ,
        @DayInWeek INT ,
        @DateOut DATE;

    SELECT  @WeekNum = CONVERT(INT, RIGHT(LEFT(@Date, 6), 2)); 

    SELECT  @DayInWeek = CONVERT(INT, RIGHT(@Date, LEN(@Date) - 6));

    SELECT  @WeekDayOfYearStart = DATEPART(WEEKDAY,
                                           LEFT(@Date, 4) + '0101');

    SELECT  @DateOut = DATEADD(DAY,
                               ( @WeekNum - 1 ) * 7 + @DayInWeek
                               - @WeekDayOfYearStart,
                               LEFT(@Date, 4) + '0101');
    RETURN  @DateOut;
END;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right the input is varchar(10). You can try this

```
DECLARE @d varchar(10)
set @d='2015/12/11'
select 
    SUBSTRING(@d, 6, charindex('/', @d, 6) - 6) as week,
    SUBSTRING(@d, charindex('/', @d, 6)+1, charindex('/', @d, len(@d) -     charindex('/', @d, 6))) as day,
DateAdd(
    day,
    cast(SUBSTRING(@d, charindex('/', @d, 6)+1, charindex('/', @d, len(@d) - charindex('/', @d, 6))) as int),
    DateADD(
        week, 
        cast(SUBSTRING(@d, 6, charindex('/', @d, 6) - 6) as int), 
        DATEFROMPARTS(cast(SUBSTRING(@d, 0, 5) as int), 1,1)
    )
) as d
```